# Square boxes instead of letters - asp.net bug, how to resolve?

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-interface

I have a asp.net page with .net controls. For a long time, many years, pages was run correctly.
But lately some signs were change from their normal display mode to squares. Looks like some encoding issue, but changing it, dosen't help.
How can I resolve this issue? Why do I see square boxes instead of some signs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the replacement of signs which were displayed as square boxes in html special box table. :)
plus/minus sign = `&plusmn;`
degree - `&#xb0;`

Answer (score 3):

The squares yous see are the Unicode Null-glyph, which is shown when the font you are using does not include representations of the character you want to show.

You might want to check which characters can not be rendered by your application, and double check if the font you use does include these. If not, you need to either stop using this characters or use another font.

Answer (score 1):

There are characters in your output that are not valid for your current browser encoding.

We would have to know more about your code to figure out how they got there.

You can look at your browser source in an editor like Vim and let us no the values of those *box* characters and what encoding your browser uses.

Comment: How to check what encoding my browser is using, and what do you mean to chceck those box characters values? When I'm opening the code of a page in Notepad++ everything looks good.